# how to traverse a javascript array with nested objects in depth?

Tags: javascript

```
var leftArr = [
    {'Header': 
        [
            {'logo_1':'logo','link_1':'Link1(#Section1)','link_2':'Link2(#Section2)','link_3':'Link3(#Section3)',
            'link_4':'Link4(#Section4)','link_5':'Link5(#Section5)','link_6':'Link6(#Section6)','link_7':'Link7(#Section7)'}
        ]
    },
    {'Banner': 
        [
            {'image_1':'Banner Image','image_2':'Logo','text_1':'Lead','text_2':'Title','text_3':'Text','clock':'Countdown','link':'Button'}
        ]
    },
    {'Social Media': 
        [
            {'twitter':'Twitter Share',
            'facebook':'Facebook Share',
            'google':'Google + Share',
            'linkedin':'Linkedin Share'},
        ]
    },

];
```

I want to traverse this array such a way so that i can get all the possible values like header, Banner,Social Media,logo,link1,link2 inside the header and so on..

Comment: This seems like a worthy endeavor. Do you have any questions about it?

Comment: Look up for in loops

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try

    leftArr.Header.Banner

Answer (score 2):

You can go inside array elements with `[index]` and inside object properties with `.property` (or also with `['property']` if it contains characters not supported in variable names or you want to make the property name dynamic).

So for example to get the `link_1` value of the `Header` you can:

```
var value = leftArr[0].Header[0].link_1;
console.log(value); // Should display 'Link1(#Section1)';
```

If you want to make it more readable you can write it as follows:

```
var header = leftArr[0].Header[0];
var link_1 = header.link_1;
//You can reuse headers to access other members
var link_7 = header.link_7;
```

If you want to build the property names dynamically you can also:

```
var links = [];
var header = leftArr[0].Header[0];
var i = 0;
while(header['link_'+i++]) {
    links[i-1] = header['link_' + i];
}
console.log(links); // Will contain: ['Link1(#Section1)','Link2(#Section2)'....'Link7(#Section7)']
```

If you want to go in depth trough all the values in an object you can:

```
for (var keyVal in header) {
    if (header.hasOwnProperty(keyVal)) {
        console.log(keyVal + ':' + header[keyVal]);
    } 
}
```

If you want to iterate over all the elements in an array then:

```
for (var index in leftArray) {
    var item = leftArray[index];
}
```

You can combine them one insde the other for convenience or use some recursive to print all the data in the object like follows:

```
function printArray(array) {
  for (var index in array) {
    console.log(index + ':');
    printItem(array[index])
  }  
}

function printObject(obj) {
  for (var keyVal in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keyVal)) {
      console.log(keyVal + ':');
      printItem(obj[keyVal])
    } 
  }  
}

function printItem(item){
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call( item ) === '[object Array]') {
    printArray(item); 
  }
  else if (typeof item === 'object' && item !== null) {
    printObject(item); 
  }
  else {
    console.log(item);
  }
}

printItem(leftArr)
```

Here you have a running plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VE44gGDzsfxgZ6iH4SkG?p=preview

Comment: for(var i=0; i<leftArr.length; i++) {
    var obj = leftArr[i];
       for (var key in obj) { 
        for (var keyVal in key) { 
          if (key.hasOwnProperty(keyVal)) {
        console.log(keyVal);
        }
        
        }
      }
         
       }

Comment: @user3756907 I can trully add that to the answer, thanks :-)

Comment: @user3756907 Check if now it's more like what you needed ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to traverse the value(like logo,Link1(#Section1),Link1(#Section1)) without using key(logo_1,link_1) as i have different array on the basis of some condition but view is same.
And idea?

Comment: logo,Link1(#Section1),Link2(#Section2) are the sub-categories of header.Like same Banner Image,Logo are sub categories of 'Banner'.
So i have to show this in a hierarchy manner.
View is same but i have different template in which category and sub categories might be different..best example is leadpages.